# Abelian group $G$ and $G/Z(G)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am taking an abstract algebra course and I am having a hard time understanding some group theory. In the course notes, it is stated that:

> If $G$ is an abelian group, then it is trivial that $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic.

Is $G/Z(G)$ to be interpreted as the **set of cosets**? So $G/Z(G) = G/G = \{G\}$? Can a set containing sets be a group? (I know in set theory everything is a set, but we are talking about group theory here) How can you even perform the group operation on sets?

Comment: Does $Z(G)$ denote the center of $G$? In that case, $Z(G) = G$ since $G$ is abelian, so $G/Z(G) \cong \{ 0 \}$, which is cyclic.

Comment: Check the definition of quotient groups.  In the usual formulation, they *always* consist of sets.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $Z(G)$ is a *normal* subgroup of $G$. In general, if $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then the set of cosets of $N$ can be endowed with a group structure: $gN \cdot hN := (g*h)N$, where $*$ is the original multiplication in $G$. The induced group is called the factor group $G/N$. You should have this written out in your nearest group theory textbook! So if $G=Z(G)$, then $G/Z(G)=G/G=\{1G\}$, the coset of $1$, the identity.